# German documents

Tags: germany, 20th-century, documents

So recently I was gifted a number of old documents , passports with photos vaccine records medal award certificates. I'm clueless as to what they all say from what I can see the young man was a nazi soldier but I could be wrong. I need to know is what I'm holding.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are different documents, about/from different people. I think it would make sense to make this question only about one document (with all of its pages).

Comment: I agree with @unor - asking for answers related to all documents in one question makes this too broad for focused Q&A.  I recommend leaving the Reisepass image here and splitting the others off into one question per document.

Comment: @Cat have you seen the new question about one of the documents in your question at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15859/19

Answer (score 1):

The document in the included image is a passport (Reisepass) issued by the Federal Republic of Germany (Bundesrepublik Deutschland) to a woman named Elfriede Schacht. If I read the stamp in the lower left-hand corner right, it was issued in Hamburg.

Comment: Lol that's all pretty obvious but thank you. So Hamburg is a place? I'm more interested in the book with nazi stamps in it, any idea what they say?

Comment: At the time of my answer only the first image was included in the question. I will look at the other ones later.

Comment: @Cat If you're surprised Hamburg is a place, it shows you have done very little researsh effort about Germany so far. I'd encourage you to learn more about Germany and come back with more precise questions here. Don't be discouraged because this particular question was closed ! Also, the book with "nazi stamps" is probably just a regular [Familienstammbuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familienstammbuch) and has nothing to do with nazism except that those stamps were made in the 1933-1945 time period.