# Seeking mother’s German passport

Tags: germany, 20th-century, documents

In a recent question ([German documents](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15818/german-documents)) an understanding of a number of German documents that had come into the possession of @Cat was sought.

I recognize the first as being the passport of my mother Elfriede Schacht and it is a document that I would very much like to have in the possession of our family.

Having glimpsed it here I am now wondering if anyone knows how I might be able to try and obtain it?